Movie where a guy (possibly the main character) pulls his teeth out at some point
This one is one of my oldest memories about a movie so please forgive the ambiguity. I barely trust the details myself.
I marked the details that I'm not sure about with *.
I remember just a few images, with virtually no plot details whatsoever:

This guy (main character*) finds a boulder-like thing in the woods*
The 'thing' is glowing green* at night
The 'thing' makes the guy want to go back every night* and dig the soil around it
It's influence grows over time and makes him behave strangely
He discovers that the 'thing' is just a very, very small piece of a larger (alien*) structure that is buried underneath it
At some point he starts pulling his teeth out in front of a wall mirror

There's also the least reliable detail: I think that the guy had a metal plate in his head.
I know it's not much to go on, thank you!

Could it be The Tommyknokers? It is a 1993 miniseries in 2 episodes adapted from a S. King's book; from IMDB:

A buried UFO slowly turns local inhabitants into gizmo-building alien mutates.

Wiki of the book
Wiki of the series
In the first episode (from wiki):

Gardner has a metal plate in his head from a skiing accident...

In the second episode (from wiki):

Gardner, meanwhile, removes one of his teeth with pliers...


Yeah, I distinctly remember all those details from the book.  Incidentally, that book caused me to sleep with the light on in my room for a month.  Creepy as hell.  The movie didn't do it justice (although it wasn't bad).

It was no where near as impactful as the book.  I love King, but I have to say almost every book I've ever read had a very disappointing end.  He's great at building up, but his payoff is usually pretty bad.  "The Tommyknockers" was no exception.  The worst was probably "It".  I was like, "Are you kidding me?!?"

@mattiav27 Yes, it is The Tommyknokers, thank you very much! I must've seen it when I was four or five years old. Thank you!

"It came from beyond space" in the 1950's
and re made in the 1970's for the ABC's "Tuesday Movie of the Week"called "Night Slaves" with James Fraciscus."(A man and his wife find themselves stranded in a small western town. He discovers that a strange force has turned the residents into zombies, and runs into a beautiful woman who he believes is the key to the mystery.)
There is also a British (UK) version. In the UK version the metal plate in his head was made of "Silver", and it was that specific metal that kept the alien brain waves from taking him over. So they make a motorcycle helmet coated with silver from melting silverware. 

This question has already an answer and the OP already said that Tommykockers is the movie he was looking for.
